# Is the construction 连A带B meaning "both A and B" a general construction or limited to fixed expressions?

Tags: grammar, expressions

The Pleco dictionary mentions the construction 连A带B meaning "both A and B" in the definition of 连, but I can't find any other discussion of this structure.

I see it in fixed expressions like 连滚带爬 (lit "both rolling and crawling", but figuratively "frantically trying to escape") and 连踢带打 (lit "to kick and hit").

- Can it be used to link anything together, or is it only used in fixed expressions?
- In fixed expressions A and B are both verbs. Does it only work for verbs?
- I've found what appear to be examples of 连A带B带C to connect 3 things together. Does it work for as many things as you want?
- Does it add any emphasis or other flavor to A+B? Simultaneity? Intensity?

Comment: 螃蟹夹豌豆——连滚带爬, haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can it be used to link anything together, or is it only used in fixed
> expressions?*

Using [連 verb A 带 verb B] create mostly idiomatic phrases when the verbs are related e.g. 消打, 哄骗, 滚爬

连消带打, 连哄带骗 and 连滚带爬 are considered fixed expressions because they are commonly spoken in day-to-day speech.

But A and B in [连 noun A 带 noun B] can be anything related or not

> *In fixed expressions A and B are both verbs. Does it only work for verbs?*

It can be nouns, e.g. 连人带马一起翻落山坡; 连店带货一起顶让给别人

> I've found what appear to be examples of 连A带B带C to connect 3 things together. Does it work for as many things as you want?

The common structure is (连)A(带)B(与及/外加/再加上)C. e.g. 连人带马与及军旗一起翻落山坡; 连店带货再加上招牌一起顶让给别人; 連哄帶騙外加小許威迫

> Does it add any emphasis or other flavor to A+B? Simultaneity? Intensity?

连A带B indicates 'also' or 'both'.

1. verb A and verb B happen at the same time or alternately.
2. noun A and noun B are both the objects

Emphasis is on 'about equal in importance'

Comment: Agree, just one more thing. "C" is not common because 4-character words are preferred in Chinese.