# What does 拼命连比带画 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> [image: photo of book]
>
> 我根本不会说法语，我当时**拼命连比带画**，想问画家能否给我再画一张刚才那个女孩的画像，结果他没有听懂。
> <sub>这世界，缺你不可, p.90.</sub>

I translate it to something like:

> I fundamentally don't speak French, and at the time I **拼命连比带画** (??), and wanted to ask the painter if he could paint another of the girl just now, but he didn't understand.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E6%88%91%E6%A0%B9%E6%9C%AC%E4%B8%8D%E4%BC%9A%E8%AF%B4%E6%B3%95%E8%AF%AD%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%91%E5%BD%93%E6%97%B6%E6%8B%BC%E5%91%BD%E8%BF%9E%E6%AF%94%E5%B8%A6%E7%94%BB%EF%BC%8C%E6%83%B3%E9%97%AE%E7%94%BB%E5%AE%B6%E8%83%BD%E5%90%A6%E7%BB%99%E6%88%91%E5%86%8D%E7%94%BB%E4%B8%80%E5%BC%A0%E5%88%9A%E6%89%8D%E9%82%A3%E4%B8%AA%E5%A5%B3%E5%AD%A9%E7%9A%84%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%EF%BC%8C%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%E4%BB%96%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E5%90%AC%E6%87%82%E3%80%82&op=translate) gives:

> I don't speak French at all. **I tried desperately to paint**, and wanted to ask if the artist could paint me another portrait of the girl just now, but he did not understand it.

The words are:

- [拼命](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%8B%BC%E5%91%BD) = "to do one's utmost"
- [连比](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%BF%9E%E6%AF%94) = "compound ratio" (???)
- [带](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%B8%A6) = "to take along"
- [画](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%94%BB) = "painting"

I don't understand how this fits together.

**Question**: What does 拼命连比带画 mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 比 = gesture

> 画 = draw

> 比画 = gesture (with hand)

Please see [連 verb A 带 verb B](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42657/is-the-construction-%E8%BF%9Ea%E5%B8%A6b-meaning-both-a-and-b-a-general-construction-or-limite/42662#42662)

> 连A带B indicates 'also' or 'both'.

> verb A and verb B happen at the same time or alternately.

> noun A and noun B are both the objects

> Emphasis is on 'about equal in importance'

Using [連 verb A 带 verb B] create mostly idiomatic phrases when the verbs are related

Example:

哄骗 --> 連哄带骗

滚爬 --> 連滚带爬

比画 --> 连比带画 (Here we just break the compound verb 比画 into two individual verbs to emphasize them both and make it idiomatic.)

*哄 and 骗 at the same time is 哄骗*

*比 and 画 at the same time is 比画*

拼命 means 'desperately; earnestly'

拼命连比带画 = desperately gesturing