# How are 连A带B and A着B different

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, difference

> 他连说带笑 / 他笑着说
>
> 他连唱带跳 / 他唱着跳

Do these sentences have the same meaning？

and if I change the position between the two verbs, do they still have the same meaning?

> 他连说带笑 / 他连笑带说
>
> 他笑着说 / 他说着笑

Answer (score 1):

**`連A帶B` is not equivalent to `A着B`.**

1. `A着B` limits both `A` and `B` to verbs, but `連A帶B` does not (they can be verbs, nouns, or adjectives).

   | Part of speech | Example sentence<sup>1</sup> | Translation |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Verbs | 眼下很多旅店為了拉客住宿都是**連蒙帶騙**。（1994年《人民日報》） | Many hostels nowadays *(lit. 'blind' and) deceive* customers for their stay. |
   | Nouns | 滅絕師太不除下劍鞘，**連劍帶鞘**，便向金花婆婆胸口點來。（金庸《倚天屠龍記》） | *With the sword and its sheath intact*, Madam Kill-All came for Golden Flower Granny's chest. |
   | Adjectives | 大夥也都**連累帶餓**快要頂不住勁兒了。（劉流《烈火金剛》） | Everyone was *both tired and hungry* and could not stand any longer. |
2. `連A帶B` sometimes parts a compound verb (e.g., `連蒙帶騙`–`蒙騙`, `連比帶劃`–`比劃`, `連諷帶刺`–`諷刺`), whereas parting them with `着` is nonsensical (i.e., it is wrong to say `*蒙着騙`, `*比着劃`, `*諷着刺`).

**Swapping `A` and `B` in `A着B` is not always permissible.**

3. There is `哭着說`, but usually not `*說着哭`. We are modifying the main action (the second verb) with an adverb of manner (made from the first verb), so you can only say, 'He said something in the manner of crying', but he couldn't have cried in the manner of saying something. `說着笑` is not an appropriate example (by that, I mean the verbs in `笑着說` are not swappable, but `說着笑` does exist with a different meaning), because it can be the stative form of the compound verb `說笑` (to joke), which is something completely different and irrelevant to our discussion.

**Swapping `A` and `B` in `連A帶B` is not always permissible.**

4. If there is no particular need for emphasis, no inherent logical order (邏輯順序), nor word order (e.g. existing compound words in point 2.), swapping is then permissible.

   | Example sentence<sup>1</sup> | Translation |
   | --- | --- |
   | 母女倆用英文爭論，仁仁**連手勢帶神色**(=連神色帶手勢)都是美國式的。（嚴歌苓《花兒與少年》） | The mother and daughter argued in English; *both* Ren Ren's *hand gesture and expression* looked American. |
5. Otherwise, swapping is not permissible.

   | Reason | Example sentence<sup>1</sup> | Translation |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Emphasis on the first verb | 「你沒走，這太好了，我都快急死了。」她**連笑帶怨**，發自內心的高興。（王朔《橡皮人》） | 'Good, you didn't leave, you're driving me crazy!' She *smiled with a tinge of complaint*, her happiness from the bottom of her heart. |
   | Logical order | 某近視小姐，為同桌斟酒，竟**連瓶帶蓋**一起倒入杯中，⋯⋯（《市場報》1994 年） | A certain shortsighted lady was pouring wine for her table. She really poured into the cup *all that was in the bottle, even the lid*. (most of what was poured in was the wine in the bottle, not the lid) |
   | Word order | 所有的人聽到我叫喊都是**連奔帶跑**，只有羅非不肯動。（陸文夫《人之窩》） | All those who heard my shouting *ran with all their might*; only Luo Fei moved not an inch. (`奔跑` is a set word; there is no `跑奔`) |
6. I think `連說帶笑` is more common than `?連笑帶說` for logical considerations: you first say something, and then laugh at what was said, not the other way round.

Reference:
<sup>1</sup> 肖奚強、余璐瑤（2017）〈“連/又/一邊A帶/又/一邊B”格式比較研究〉。南京師大學報(社會科學版)，6，137–146。

Answer (score 0):

From my answer [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42657/is-the-construction-%E8%BF%9Ea%E5%B8%A6b-meaning-both-a-and-b-a-general-construction-or-limite):

> Using [連 verb A 带 verb B] create mostly idiomatic phrases when the verbs are related e.g. 消打, 哄骗, 滚爬

> 连消带打, 连哄带骗 and 连滚带爬 are considered fixed expressions because they are commonly spoken in day-to-day speech

> 连A带B indicates 'also' or 'both'.

> **verb A and verb B happen at the same time or alternately**.

> noun A and noun B are both the objects

> Emphasis is on about equal in importance

[A 着 B] is a simple grammar structure of using the conjunction 着 (while) to connect two verb phrases

[verb A 着 verb B] = [verb B while verb A] = **verb A and verb B happen at the same time or alternately**

The difference:

- The verbs in [連 A 带 B] must be a single character verb and must be related. Phrases in this structure are mostly idiomatic. Example: 连消带打, 连哄带骗, 连滚带爬
- The verbs in [A 着 B] can be a single character verb or a complete verb phrase. The two verbs don't need to be related. It is just how the conjunction 着 functions. Example: 笑着说, 跑着開槍, 坐着喝咖啡, 喝着咖啡等人

> *and if I change the position between the two verbs is it still has the same meaning? 他连说带笑 / 他连笑带说 ，他笑着说 / 他说着笑*

- You cannot switch the position of the two verbs in [連 A 带 B] when the two verbs are from a compound word
- Verb A in [A 着 B] must be in a continuous state and sometimes it is illogical to switch. For example, you can 跑着開槍 (fire while running) but you cannot 開槍着跑