# How to literally translate this: 看完连书带钱交给摊主?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

租借小人书很便宜，在摊里看，每册1分钱，选好书坐下就看，看完连书带钱交给摊主；

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 20.

How to literally translate this: 看完连书带钱交给摊主?

I know that 看完 here means reading finished or reading completed, 书 means book, 钱 means money, 给 means to give to and 摊主 means stall owner. But I don't know the meaning of the other characters. For example 连 means to link, to join or to connect? Or continuously, repeatedly? 带 means belt or to take? 交 means to intersect or to cross?

Comment: 连书带钱: book together with money (rental payment).

Comment: 连A带B; https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42657/is-the-construction-%e8%bf%9ea%e5%b8%a6b-meaning-both-a-and-b-a-general-construction-or-limite

Answer (score 3):

交给 means to give. 我把这本书交给你 = I give this book to you.

连A带B is an fixed-phrase that simply means "A and B". Hence "连书带钱交给摊主" means "to give both the book and the money (rent) to the stall owner". Note that 把 is not used here. If we do not use the 连A带B construction then we should have 把书和钱交给摊主.

Answer (score 3):

看完**连**书**带**钱交给摊主. = 看完以后，把书**和**钱**一起**交给摊主.

连A带B = 把A和B一起. 连 and 带 have the same meaning as 和。For example,

我吃了一口辣椒，**连**鼻涕**带**眼泪都出来了. = Because I ate a bite of chili my nose **and** tears all came out **together**.

There are many idioms with this usage, such as 连喊带叫, 连哭带闹, 连说带唱, 连打带骂, 连吃带拿. Some may have a similar meaning as 边A边B or 又A又B. = not only but also.

Answer (score 0):

他们连儿带女都不能救: neither their sons nor their daughters can they save
连妇女带孩童也都欢乐: both the women and the children were happy

连书带钱: both the book and the money

租借小人书很便宜，
Renting Little People's books is cheap
在摊里看，
read at the stand,
每册1分钱，
each book costs 1 penny (to read),
选好书坐下就看，
choose a good book, sit down and read,
看完连书带钱交给摊主；
(when) you are finished reading give the book and the money to the stallholder;

Answer (score 0):

“[交](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%BA%A4)” here is "give", repetition with “给” in semantics. And "交给" be used commonly in modern Chinese as a compound word in semantics, which just means "give (something) to (somebody)".

“连”,“带”, here both means "with/and", another repetition, and still be used in common in Chinese.

These are idiomatic usage, just get be accustomed to it.

give the book and money to stall owner.

give the book with money to stall owner.

or, give both book and money to stall owner.